# Which files can be found by \(pdf)filesize?

Tags: pdftex, filesystem-access

Compiling the following code with pdfTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
1 \pdffilesize{XITS-Regular.otf} \par
2 \pdffilesize{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/xits/XITS-Regular.otf} \par
3 \pdffilesize{book.cls} \par
\end{document}
```

It gives

```
1
2 270496
3 23147
```

In XeTeX, the `\filesize` command gives the same result. Why `XITS-Regular.otf` cannot be found by `\(pdf)filesize`? Is there any description of which files can be searched?

Actually I use the LaTeX3's `\file_if_exist:nTF` to check if something exists. `\file_if_exist:nTF {XITS-Regular.otf}` goes to the false branch so I think it's due to the `\pdffilesize` primitives.

Comment: it uses the same search path as \input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\pdffilesize` command uses the same search path as `\input` as well as `\file_if_exist:nTF`.

However, you can do a search in the whole TeX tree with `kpsewhich`:

```
\everyeof{\noexpand}\endlinechar=-1
\pdffilesize{\input|"kpsewhich XITS-Regular.otf" }

\bye
```

With TeX Live 2020, the same can be

```
\everyeof{\noexpand}\endlinechar=-1
\pdffilesize{\input{|"kpsewhich XITS-Regular.otf"}}

\bye
```

For LaTeX, use `\@@input`.

This will print 270496.

How does this work? When the file name passed to `\input` (the primitive one) begins with `|`, the TeX engines (except for “Knuth TeX” that enables no extension) interpret this as a “pipe”.

The rest of the file name should be a shell command enclosed in double quotes; the TeX run is suspended and the shell command is executed, piping its output to TeX, that then resumes its job.

It's essentially the same mechanism as `$(command arguments)` in the Bash shell.

Some commands, among which `kpsewhich` are deemed “safe”, so they're executed under “restricted shell escape”, which is by default enabled. The full list is

```
bibtex bibtex8 extractbb gregorio kpsewhich 
makeindex  repstopdf r-mpost texosquery-jre8
```

Other shell commands can be run, but you need to enable `-shell-escape`.

Comment: Could you please explain the relation between `\input` and the kpathsea library, i.e. why `kpsewhich` can find `XITS-Regular.otf` but `\input` can't?

Comment: @stone-zeng `\input|"<shell command>"` executes the `<shell command>` and passes the output to TeX. Since `kpsewhich` is among the “safe” commands, you don't need to enable `-shell-escape`.

Comment: Emm, I mean that since (pdf)TeX is based on the kpathsea library, why we still need an extra `|"kpsewhich ..."` and why a single `\input` command can't find an `.otf` file?

Comment: @stone-zeng `\input` only looks in the directories pointed to by the variable `TEXINPUTS` (which does not contain font directories). But here I'm using the “pipe” feature that is not influenced by any variable.

Comment: @stone-zeng There are different parts of the `texmf` tree for different parts of the TeX system; the 'macro side' doesn't look at font files, that's down to the internals of `\font` (or Lua or ...)